# Using a math operator inside a 'cases' environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

When I do this:

```
\begin{equation}
 b_i =
\begin{cases}
arg \min_{\forall p \in B} d(a_i, p) & \text{if } d(a_i, b_i) < D_{max}
\\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

the `_` doesn't cause the following text to go below `\min`, but rather appear as a subscript. Is it possible to make a `\min` expression with the following text below it inside a `cases` environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does adding `\displaystyle` do it for you?  id est:

```
\begin{equation}
    b_i =
    \begin{cases}
    arg \displaystyle\min_{\forall p \in B} d(a_i, p) & \text{if } d(a_i, b_i) < D_{max}
    \\
    \text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't think I needed \displaystyle since I was already in an 'equation' environment, but I guess 'cases' takes it "out" of equation mode. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidDoria i think you can use the `dcases` environment instead of `cases` if you don't want it in text style, as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment)

Comment: `cases` switches one size down, which means `\displaystyle`->`\textstyle`. In `\textstyle`, all sub/super-sripts are put on the left.

Answer (score 5):

You can use commands `\limits` and `\nolimits` to control where the subscripts are places. As well, you might want the `arg min` look better, as shown in the following example (notice you have to declare the command `\argmin` yourself):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

%% HERE
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 b_i =
\begin{cases}
%% HERE
\argmin\limits_{\forall p \in B} d(a_i, p) & \text{if } d(a_i, b_i) < D_{max}
\\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can omit the `\limits` command if you use `dcases` environment instead of `cases`. They differ in the math style inside -- `dcases` keep `\displaystyle` inside.

Comment: You might also point to the `dcases` environment provided by `mathtools`.